# Thread-safety during construction

Tags: java, multithreading

In *"Java Concurrency in Practice"* book there is a `MonitorVehicleTracker` code example, which is stated to be thread-safe.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class MonitorVehicleTracker {
    @GuardedBy("this") private final Map<String, MutablePoint> locations;

    public MonitorVehicleTracker(Map<String, MutablePoint> locations) {
        this.locations = deepCopy(locations);
    }

    public synchronized Map<String, MutablePoint> getLocations() {
        return deepCopy(locations);
    }

    public synchronized MutablePoint getLocation(String id) {
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        return loc == null ? null : new MutablePoint(loc);
    }

    public synchronized void setLocation(String id, int x, int y) {
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        if (loc == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such ID: " + id);
        loc.x = x;
        loc.y = y;
    }

    private static Map<String, MutablePoint> deepCopy(Map<String, MutablePoint> m) {
        Map<String, MutablePoint> result = new HashMap<String, MutablePoint>();

        for (String id : m.keySet())
            result.put(id, new MutablePoint(m.get(id)));

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }
}
```

But lets consider the case when constructor `locations` argument is *modified* by another thread during `deepCopy()` call. This could cause `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown while iterating through `keySet()`.

So does this mean that `MonitorVehicleTracker` is not completely thread-safe? Or *thread-safety* appears only after object construction is finished, and calling code is responsible for ensuring that `locations` will not be modified during `MonitorVehicleTracker` instantiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the class is still thread-safe.

If the object fails to initialize then this doesn't mean its class cease be thread-safe. It is a thread-safe class that failed to initialise because it's argument was wrongly modified by a different thread breaking its `thread-saftey` contract.

Comment: Right; The `Map` implementation of `locations` is not thread-safe, but `MonitorVehicleTracker` is.

Comment: Does the same apply to the case when class invariants are broken during construction because of threads interleaving?

Comment: @PavloViazovskyy I would say so